# WinForms / .NET - Why throw caught exception

Tags: winforms, exception

I saw some codes here in the application I'm working with:

```
    Try
        //Some code
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
```

I wonder why do they have to throw the exception that they caught? I don't get it. Well, I don't have any contacts to the developer of this app that's why I'm asking here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to syntax of Try Catch they will do so.

Comment: But why? I think it's nonsense. Catch and throw? Why?

Comment: I can only think of 1 reason why he made this code.. Some methods/objects need to be defined inside a trycatch, but maybe he wanted to let the program crash for debug purposes? If you don't create the try/catch you can't build it..

Comment: It's impossible to know "why" he did it. Perhaps he intended to handle it differently and this was just temporary filler code. Perhaps he didn't know any better.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two reasons:

- There have been, or the author has planned for, additional code before the `throw`.
- Debugging purposes. The code doesn't do anything as it stands now, but it allows for a breakpoint to be placed on the `throw` statement.